# Is it a good idea to build a portfolio website using flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I started learning flutter last 2 months. I already built more than 3 apps. I am now wondering Is it a good idea to build a website using flutter?

Comment: There are downsides of using flutter for production grade web because it is still relatively new. But you really should try and decide on your own.

Answer (score 1):

I think this kind of question does not fit SO policies. However, yes it could be helpful and show your skills on `flutter` and `dart langugage`. You can use [this template](https://awesomeopensource.com/project/Codelessly/FlutterMinimalWebsite) at the first point.